# What is a Gnome panel "OAFIID" error message and how can I fix it?

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel

When I started my laptop this morning I got a very strange message.
I have no idea of what it means, or what I should do.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received this message because, for some reason, the trash applet was unable to load in to your Gnome Panel.  You can click Delete, then try adding the Trash manually by right clicking your bar, and adding the applet from there.

If you get the problem again, I'd recommend opening a Terminal and running:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-applets
```

Make sure you don't have anything important open and unsaved then click Ctrl+Alt+Backspace and log in again.

Comment: This is the result of a bug in the Gnome session. Just click "don't delete", and log out and back in (no need to fully reboot) and the applet should reappear.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the applet did not start up properly. If its not much of a pain, you can click delete. right click on the panel, and select the trash applet. Or you can just click dont delete, and let it load automatically on the next restart.